# a timeit function for F#

Tags: .net, f#

I am trying to write something like

```
let timeit (x:'a->'b) =
    let start = System.DateTime.Now
    x
    let duration = System.DateTime.Now - start
    printfn "time usage = %A" duration.Milliseconds 
    ()
```

it works for

```
let matrixtest() =
    let x = vector[1.;2.;4.]
    let y = matrix[[1.;2.;4.;];[3.;4.;9.;]]
    printfn "%A" (y * x)
    ()
```

but not for

```
let rec fib x = 
        match x with
        | 0 | 1 -> 1
        | n -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

sa F# is static typed.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even in the matrix case you need to apply the function to a value.  Try this:

```
let timeit f v =
  let start = System.DateTime.Now
  let result = f v
  let duration = System.DateTime.Now - start
  printfn "time usage = %A" duration.Milliseconds 
  result
```

Aequitarum Custos is right about using the `StopWatch` class, though.

Comment: how about having two/more parameters for f ?

Comment: If you have more parameters, you can use currying: the timing of f x y becomes '(timeit f x) y', since (f x) is a function that only needs a y. And '(timeit g x y) z' times the calculation of g x y z, etc..

Comment: Hmm. No comment editing. I meant timeit (f x) y. Parentheses matter in this case. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 10):

Putting it together

```
let timeit f v = 
    let watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    watch.Start()
    let res = f v 
    watch.Stop()
    printfn "Needed %f ms" (watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    res
```

Comment: Note that this works for any function; you can apply it to an arbitrary code block a la: "timeit (fun()->arbitraryBlockOfCode) ()".  That is, wrap a block of code in a lambda to pass arbitrary code to the function.

Answer (score 8):

When testing code in F# interactive, you can use the `#time` directive to time each piece of code you send to/enter in F# interactive. Example:

```
> #time;;

--> Timing now on

> let slowstring = List.fold (+) "" [for i in 1..10000 -> string i];;
Real: 00:00:00.544, CPU: 00:00:00.546, GC gen0: 464, gen1: 37, gen2: 0

val slowstring : string =
  "1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435"+[38833 chars]

> let quickstring = String.concat "" [for i in 1..10000 -> string i];;
Real: 00:00:00.008, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

val quickstring : string =
  "1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435"+[38833 chars]

>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch

Much more accurate in timing.

This is assuming your getting a result of 0 seconds, which isn't DateTime.Now not working, it's just poor accuracy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx